# How to unit test non-exported class in UWP component (C++/WinRT)

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I'm looking for some guidance on my strategy for unit testing UWP components.

I am developing a UWP component using the C++/WinRT projection. This component contains a helper class that manages communication with a Bluetooth device. I would like to write unit tests for that helper class (BthDevice) without exporting them to the UWP component's interface.

I started by following some guidelines for testing non-exported DLL classes. Specifically, I created a new UWP unit test project. I explicitly added my project's include directory, included BthDevice.h, and added the class' BthDevice.obj to the linker settings. I fought a few linker errors, and now it's falling over because I'm using precompiled headers in the UWP component. I've given up for now.

It feels like this should be a simple task, and that I'm going about it the wrong way. Any guidance is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: You can immediately access an [implementation type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/faq#what-do-the-projected-type-and-the-implementation-type-mean), as long as [the API is implemented in the consuming project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis#if-the-api-is-implemented-in-the-consuming-project).

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to unit test an implementation type from a UWP Unit Test project. So, the implementation type is NOT implemented in the consuming project.

Comment: If you `#include` the implementation file into a compilation unit of your test project, then that implementation type is implemented in the consuming project. At least that appears to be a workable solution, although I never used the built-in testing framework.